# How does OS X Mavericks' tagging work, under the covers?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, tagging

With OS X Mavericks, we can now tag our files. Does anyone have a guess as to how they do this in the backend, efficiently?

Obviously not looking for specific answers, but theories on what structures they use would be interesting to read.

Comment: Frankly, no clue. But if I have to guess, you can simply have a linked list with the file path as the node.

Answer (score 2):

They're stored in an extended attribute named `com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags`, in binary property list format, as an array of strings. Each tag string is either just a tag name, or a tag name followed by a linefeed character and a numeric color ID. Spotlight then indexes these along with the file's other attributes for fast searches. Also, for a bit of backwards compatibility, the most recently applied tag color is set as the label color.

See [John Siracusa's review at Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/os-x-10-9/9/#tags-implementation) for examples and more details.